# UItableview cell Dyanmic height with UItableview inside the UItableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

My requirement to place list of feeds & images in tableview and along with that each feed comments also should display along with feed.

For that i took the Inner uitableview inside the UItableview cell. And the comments tableview height should be dynamic.How can i update the Feeds tableview height according to the height of Comments tableview (Inner tableview).

[image]

this sample picture i attached contains 10 comments,but with the static size i can able to show only one comment,I tried to get the comments tableview content size height and reload the feeds tableview ,it causes disgusting behaviour.

Can any one please give me a better approach for this.

Comment: Why don't you use multiple sections?

Comment: «You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.» [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/). As UITableView is a subview of UIScrollView, this rule applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem in this way.

Instead of multiple tableviews,i went for multiple sections.I kept Feed Message/image section header and comments as rows for that section.That work's great.

@wain thanks for your hint.This would help for others.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Wain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain) mentioned in the comments, the best approach would probably be to use multiple sections rather than a `UITableView` within a cell. Each section could be a post with the first cell being the "post" and subsequent cells being comments. Alternatively, you could make the "post" be the section header if you want it to stick to the top of the screen as you scroll the comments.

If this is not possible (for instance, if you're already using sections for another purpose), what you could do is calculate the total height of your "sub-tables" before building the main table and store those values to use as the cell heights for your main table. For instance, if you know that your first post has 7 comments that will occupy 300pt height total, along with a post that is 50pt, you know that your cell will need to have 350pt height. If you do go this route, which I still think is not the best approach, make sure that you turn off scrolling on the sub-tables. This will reduce the risk of having conflicting scroll views that will annoy and confuse the end user.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to calculate the size of each cell of your table view dynamically. I had a requirement where I had to do a facebook like table view where the contents maybe of variable height. Especially the text. So I tried to find the required height of all the variable sized contents inside my cells contentView and set the height of the cell accordingly. Here are some code snippets:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    JHAlertDetailViewCell *cell = (JHAlertDetailViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"JHAlertDetailViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    JHAlert *alert = [self.alerts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self configureCell:cell withItem:alert];
    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [self heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)configureCell:(JHAlertDetailViewCell *)cell withItem:(JHAlert *)item{
    // In this method, you can actually populate all the contents of your cell and calculate the total     //height also

}

- (CGFloat)heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static JHAlertDetailViewCell *sizingCell = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sizingCell = [self.alertsTV dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"JHAlertDetailViewCell"];
        if (sizingCell==nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"JHAlertDetailViewCell" owner:self options:Nil];
            sizingCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }


    });

    [self configureCell:sizingCell withItem:[self.alerts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return sizingCell.whiteView.bounds.size.height+20; // Here, whiteView is the UIOutlet of the main background view of the cell. Its height as calculated in the configureCell: method is used here to return the required height of the cell.
}
```